# can i combine two css classes per single html div or span element?

Tags: css

i have the below code doing what i want, but wanted to see if i can simplify it into a single line and not use two html elements

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .FirstLetter{color:White; background:Blue; border:1px black solid; padding-top:10px; padding-left:10px;}
        .Spaced{letter-spacing: 5px;}   
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <span class="FirstLetter">
            R
        </span>
        <span class="Spaced">
            ealtime Account Activiation
        </span>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

can i get away with a single inline text in a html element like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
   <style type="text/css">
        .FirstLetter{color:White; background:Blue; border:1px black solid; padding-top:10px; padding-left:10px;}
        .Spaced{letter-spacing: 5px;}   
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div class="FirstLetter Spaced">
        Realtime Account Activiation
    </div>

    <div class=""FirstLetter Spaced"">
        Announcements
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why didn't you just create a local file with the new HTML and load it into your browser? My guess is no since the FirstLetter CSS style would be applied to all the text in the DIV as opposed to just the first letter in the first sample. Though you may be able to use [http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pseudo_first-letter.asp] if your targeted browsers support the first-letter pseudo-element

Comment: i can use span, actually found span better cause it doesn't stretch the entire length horizontally !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the pseudo-element [`:first-letter`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-letter) to achieve what you need adding it right after the class `.FirstLetter` of your css rule like:

`.FirstLetter:first-letter{color:White; background:Blue; border:1px black solid; padding-top:10px; padding-left:10px;}` .

Here an example using the second part of your html: http://jsbin.com/eqicu4

Of course it needs some modifications to make it exactly how it's in the first example.